# Python unittest not running specified test

Tags: python, testing

I'm currently working my way through Python Crash Course and have run into a problem during the testing chapter. I've went through with a comb, explained it to my imaginary rubber duck, and can't see at all where I'm going wrong.

Running the test file gives me "Run 0 tests in 0.000s" but no errors that I can see.
The first block is from my file "survey.py", and the second is the test file "testSurvey.py"

Any help is hugely appreciated.

```
class AnonymousSurvey():

    def __init__(self, question):
        self.question = question
        self.responses = []

    def showQuestion(self):
        print(self.question)

    def storeResponse(self, newResponse):
        self.responses.append(newResponse)

    def showResults(self):
        print("The survey results are")
        for response in self.responses:
            print("-- " + response)



import unittest

from survey import AnonymousSurvey

class TestAnonymousSurvey(unittest.TestCase):
    def TestStoreSingleResponse(self):
        question = "What is your favourite language?"
        mySurvey = AnonymousSurvey(question)
        responses = ["English", "Latin", "Franglais"]
        for response in responses:
            mySurvey.storeResponse(response)

        for response in responses:
            self.assertIn(response, mySurvey.responses)

unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test methods should start with keyword 'test'
like 'test_storing_single_response()'

Pytest identifies method starting with 'test' as a testcase

check out [pytest good practice](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html)

```
    Conventions for Python test discovery
    pytest implements the following standard test discovery:



 - If no arguments are specified then collection starts from testpaths
   (if configured) or the current directory. Alternatively, command line
   arguments can be used in any combination of directories, file names
   or node ids.
 - Recurse into directories, unless they match norecursedirs.
 - In those directories, search for test_*.py or *_test.py files,
   imported by their test package name.
 - From those files, collect test items:

     -    test prefixed test functions or methods outside of class
     - test prefixed test functions or methods inside Test prefixed test
   classes (without an __init__ method)
```

Comment: Thank you mate, it was as simple as changing TestStoreSingleResponse to testScoreSimpleResponse! Truly appreciated :)